# How to cut specific part of string in java?

Tags: java, string, cut

I'm facing with the problem how to cut specific part of string below:

```
     - VIN                : A9 C1 C4 C5 C6 E9 F2 F5 F8 G1 G7 H4 H6 I1 I4 I5
                            I6 I7 J1 K8 L3 L5 M4 O2 P6 Q9 R3 S3 T9 U3 V2 V3
                            V9 W5 Z5
     - CODES              : A9 C1 C4 C5 C6 E9 F2 F5 F8 G1 G7 H4 H6 I1 I4 I5
                            I6 I7 J1 K8 L3 L5 M4 O2 P6 Q9 R3 S3 T9 U3 V2 V3
                            V9 W5 Y4 Y8
```

1. I want to cut the part from A9 to Z5 and place it into List of Strings (from VIN section)
2. Words VIN and CODE are always the same but codes in each section can be different that why I canot simply take index of A9 and Z5 and get everything between

Comment: Where does the `String` start and end? Post some code of what you've tried.

Comment: Don't get it. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Do you know `String.substring`, `String.split` or even what is a regex ? It should be a good start for you. I can help you more if you don't try to solve that yourself.

Comment: @Radek can't you just split whole `String` to two lists and iterate over it? Simply `str.split(" ")` will do. You just have to remember to remove empty values.

Comment: Specify which parts of the string will always be there, for example, are those colons always there at the start of the section you want? Is that hyphen always there on the line after? Do you just want the VIN value and ignore CODES? Will the whitespace always be the same? Does the same VIN and CODES section repeat in the same file, or separate files? Are they even coming from files?

Comment: Down voted, because OP has shown barely any effort and no code provided.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using the literal "CODES" to get the first half, then use [a regular expression matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to iterate over the codes:

```
final String vin = myString.split("CODES")[0];
final List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][0-9]").matcher(vin);
while (matcher.find()) codes.add(matcher.group());
```

Comment: I was waiting for OP to try that first. Doesn't seems to have tried a lot. I like the idea of the pattern here, it work as long as the codes remains a letter followed with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try (only if the string always respect the same patter):

```
String vinCode = myString.subString(myString.indexOf(":") + 2); // Blank space
vinCode = vinCode.subString(0, vinCode.indexOf("-"));
```

As AxelH noticed, this is equivalent to

```
String vinCode = myString.subString(myString.indexOf(":") + 2, vinCode.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

But I think that two steps is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your sugestions. The problem is not that easy, cuz the string itself contains many sentens like "- Word  :  something" I write this piece of code to solve it:

```
public List<String> getModelOptionCodesList(String calcPreview){
    List<String> modelOptionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String modelOptionsFromVinPosition = "VIN   : ";
    String modelOptionsPosition = "CODES     : ";
    Integer startIndexOfMOCodes;
    Integer endIndexOfMOCodes;
    String moCodes;

    startIndexOfMOCodes = calcPreview.indexOf(modelOptionsFromVinPosition);
    endIndexOfMOCodes = calcPreview.indexOf(modelOptionsPosition);
    startIndexOfMOCodes += modelOptionsFromVinPosition.length();

    moCodes = calcPreview.substring(startIndexOfMOCodes, endIndexOfMOCodes - 3).replaceAll("\\n\\s+", " ");
    modelOptionsList = Arrays.asList(moCodes.split("\\s"));
    modelOptionsList.removeIf(String::isEmpty);

    return modelOptionsList;
}
```